# Run test in separate file with unittest.main

Tags: databricks, python-unittest

I create a notebook which looks like the following:

```
import unittest
class TestHelpers(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_trivial2(self):
        self.assertEqual(True,True)
        

unittest.main(argv=[''],exit=False)
```

When running the notebook, everything works fine. Now, I try to move the test out to a separate `*.py` file:

Notebook code:

```
import unittest

unittest.main(argv=[''],exit=False)
```

New Python file (in same repo):

```
import unittest
class TestHelpers(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_trivial2(self):
        self.assertEqual(True,True)
```

When running the notebook I always get

> Ran 0 test

I tried to add the path as argv such as

```
unittest.main(argv=['/Workspace/Repos/XXX/repo'],exit=False)
```

but the `*.py` file is not discorved

What do I have to hand over to argv so that the py file is identified

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniil for the link:

```
import unittest

unittest.main(module="simple_test",argv=[''],exit=False)
```

makes the job!